# Show set of all differentiable functions $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Show set of all differentiable functions $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is uncountable.

I think we have to use the Schröder-Bernstein theorem which states that if $|A| \leq |B|$,
and $|A| \geq |B|$ then $|A|=|B|$.

Need some help.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem that was posed did not ask you to show that there were (continuum) many differentiable functions but just uncountably many. So showing that there are at least (continuum) many differentiable functions should do it.

Comment: See also: [Cardinality of the set of differentiable functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610323/cardinality-of-the-set-of-differentiable-functions)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint:** For $c\in\mathbb R$ consider $f(x)=c$.

Comment: is that a bijection from f to R?

Comment: @josh You did not asked that your set has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ but that it is uncountalbe hence that it is not countable.

Comment: sorry but i still dont understand why its uncountable, can you explain? uncountable means that the cardinality of the set isnt equal to |N| right?

Comment: @josh Each constant function is differentiable therefore you have the injection $$H: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathrm{Your\, set}$$ where one real $c$ is sent to the constant differential function $f(x)=c$

Comment: @josh No. Uncountable means it is strictly greater than $|\Bbb N|$. $|\{1,2,3\}|\neq |\Bbb N|$ but they certainly $\{1,2,3\}$ is countable.

Comment: @clark right, so this shows that |R| < set of continuous functions?

Comment: @josh this is right. But it also proves this inequality for the differential functions

Answer (score 5):

To show that this set has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$ proceed as follows.
For the one direction notice that your the set of differentiable function is a subsets of the continuous functions so their cardinality is less or equal their cardinality.

A continuous functions is uniquely determined if we know the values it takes at the rationals.
Therefore they have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Q}}$ but $$\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Q}}\cong \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\cong {\left (\mathbb{2^\mathbb{N}}\right )}^\mathbb{N} \cong 2^{\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}\cong2^\mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{R}. $$
Which proved that the continuous function have less or equal cardinality than $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at this problem is to use the basics of metric spaces. As we know that continuous image of connected set is connected and $[0,1]$ is connected subset of $R$. Since,   differentiable maps from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$  must be continuous though. Now, using continuous image of connected sets is connected it is clear that the set of all the continuous maps from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ must be connected subset of $R$ and The only connected subsets of R are the intervals (bounded or unbounded, open orclosed or neither) which must be uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

Take the collection of functions $f_\alpha(x) = \alpha$, with $\alpha \in [0,1]$. Since $[0,1]$ is uncountable, and each $f_\alpha$ is distinct, the set $\{ f_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in [0,1]}$ is uncountable.

Here $A=[0,1]$, $B= \{f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} | f \text{ is differentiable} \}$, and $\phi:A \to B$ given by $\phi(\alpha) = f_\alpha$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(f)_r:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a family of functions over $\mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=x^r$. Clearly differentiable, since exponential. Clearly uncountable since defined over $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

In a more general way, using @mathemagician idea, take any one differentiable function over $x$ and make it into a function over $ rx : r \in \mathbb R $ and obtain a continuum worth of differentiable functions through $f(x) \rightarrow f(rx): r \in \mathbb R $ each such $f(r_ox)$ is differentiable for all $r_o \in \mathbb R$ , as the composition of differentiable functions, and there are $\mathbb R=\mathbb c$ such functions.

You can e.g., take $  \sin x \rightarrow sin(rx) : r \in \mathbb R$ . Any one differentiable function will do.

You can see how to use a similar argument to show there are countably-many non-differentiable functions  $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$