# Cardinality of the set of differentiable functions

Tags: cardinals

Is the cardinality of 
$$X = \{f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R \;|\; f \text{ is differentiable everywhere}\}$$
the same as $\Bbb R$?
How to prove it?

Comment: I am fairly certain that this question was asked before, can't seem to find a link at the moment though.

Comment: The answer below will give you half of what you need. For the other half, construct of set with cardinality of $\Bbb R$ of everywhere differentiable functions.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  This is also true of the set of *continuous* functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, which contains all differentiable functions.  Try using the fact that a continuous function is determined by its values on the rational numbers (a countable set).

Comment: To extend to this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17914/cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-real-functions-of-real-variable/17915#17915